# NSDictionary query

Tags: ios6, key, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm new to iOS 6 and just wanted to post a question regarding the use of NSDictionary or MutuableDictionary.

I'm used to the Android method ShardPreferences where I can write data in key/value format and overwrite etc. etc. Any SharedPreferences file can also be accessed from any scene, like a global class.

Am I looking at the right classes for what I want to do?

Once created can the content be accessed from any scene/class?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NSUserDefaults`

> With the `NSUserDefaults` class, you can save settings and properties
>   related to application or user data.

For example, you could save a profile image set by the user or a default color scheme for the application.

> The objects will be saved in what is known as the iOS “defaults
>   system”. The iOS defaults system is available throughout all of the
>   code in your app, and any data saved to the defaults system will
>   persist through application sessions. This means that even if the user
>   closes your application or reboots their phone, the saved data will
>   still be available the next time they open the app!

With NSUserDefaults you can save objects from the following class types:

```
 - NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary
```

If you want to store any other type of object, such as a UIImage, you will typically need to archive it or wrap it in an instance of NSData, NSNumber, or NSString.

Example

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedPref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[sharedPref setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
NSString *myString = [sharedPref stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

That is the persisted, globally accessible "preferences" for an application.

NSDictionary is just like java.util.Map in Android.